# Make flex items automatically re-size to fill space when sibling is removed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, flexbox

I've got four flex boxes which I'd like to close and have the others automatically resize to fit the newly empty space.

I think there's something simple wrong with my CSS, as currently the close button closes every box.

Can you spot where I've gone wrong?

```css
#separator {
  width: 20%;
}
#firstbox {
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
#secondbox {
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
#thirdbox {
  width: 20%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
#fourthbox img {
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="trancontent">
  <div id="separator">
    <br>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <div id="firstbox">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>CLOSE</span>
    <?php include 'test2.php';?>
  </div>
  <div id="secondbox">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>CLOSE</span>
    <?php include 'test2.php';?>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdbox">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>CLOSE</span>
    <?php include 'test2.php';?>
  </div>
  <div id="fourthbox">
    <img src="greek.jpg" alt="Greek Translation" height="400" width="400">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By giving flex items `flex-grow: 1`, they each will expand to consume available space. Hence, if an item is removed, its siblings will automatically expand into that new space.

Try this simple approach:

```css
flex-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
}

/* key rule */
flex-container > * { flex: 1; }
/* shorthand for flex-grow: 1, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: 0 */

/* non-essential decorative styles */
#firstbox  { background-color: aqua; }
#secondbox { background-color: pink; }
#thirdbox  { background-color: lightgreen; }
flex-container > * { width: 100px;  border: 1px dashed black; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<flex-container>
  <div id="firstbox">
    <span id='close' onclick="parentNode.remove()">Close Box #1</span>
    <?php include 'test2.php';?>
  </div>
  <div id="secondbox">
    <span id='close' onclick="parentNode.remove()">Close Box #2</span>
    <?php include 'test2.php';?>
  </div>
  <div id="thirdbox">
    <span id='close' onclick="parentNode.remove()">Close Box #3</span>
    <?php include 'test2.php';?>
  </div>
</flex-container>
```